# Spring batch exiting after task done. How to trigger on every 5 minuters interval

Tags: java, spring-batch

Spring batch exiting after task done. How to trigger on every 5 minuters interval.

My Spring batch is getting complete once the job is done `Process finished with exit code 0`

I want my batch to run after every 5 minutes.

Here is what i am trying

Job Runner :

```
@Component
public class JobRunner implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired
    private JobLauncher jobLauncher;

    @Autowired
    private Job jobA;

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {

        JobParameters jobParameters =
                new JobParametersBuilder()
                        .addLong("time", System.currentTimeMillis())
                        .toJobParameters();

        jobLauncher.run(jobA, jobParameters);
        System.out.println("JOB Execution completed!");
    }
}
```

Job Launcher :

```
public class JobLaunch {
    private final Job job;
    private final org.springframework.batch.core.launch.JobLauncher jobLauncher;

    @Autowired
    public JobLaunch(Job job, org.springframework.batch.core.launch.JobLauncher jobLauncher) {
        this.job = job;
        this.jobLauncher = jobLauncher;
    }

    @Scheduled(fixedRate = 1000)
    public void runSpringBatchExampleJob() throws JobParametersInvalidException, JobExecutionAlreadyRunningException, JobRestartException, JobInstanceAlreadyCompleteException {
        jobLauncher.run(job, newExecution());
    }

    private JobParameters newExecution() {
        Map<String, JobParameter> parameters = new HashMap<>();

        JobParameter parameter = new JobParameter(new Date());
        parameters.put("currentTime", parameter);

        return new JobParameters(parameters);
    }
}
```

Batch config :

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class BatchConfing {
    @Bean
    public ItemReader<LeadDTO> itemReader(DataSource dataSource) {
        // reader code
    }

    @Bean
    public ItemWriter<LeadDTO> itemWriter(){
        // writer code
    }
    @Bean
    public JobExecutionListener listener() {
        return new ScheduelListener();
    }
    @Bean
    public Step stepA(@Qualifier("itemReader") ItemReader<dto> reader,
                      @Qualifier("itemWriter") ItemWriter<dto> writer,
                      StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory) {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("stepA")
                .<dto,dto>chunk(2)
                .reader(reader)
                .writer(writer)
                .build()
                ;
    }

    @Bean
    public Job jobA(@Qualifier("stepA") Step exampleJobStep,
                    JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory){
        return jobBuilderFactory.get("jobA")
                .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                .listener(listener())
                .flow(exampleJobStep)
                .end()
                //.start(stepA())
                .build()
                ;
    }

}
```

Job Scheduler :

```
public class ScheduelListener implements JobExecutionListener {

    @Override
    public void beforeJob(JobExecution jobExecution) {

        System.out.println("Job started at: "+ jobExecution.getStartTime());
        System.out.println("Status of the Job: "+jobExecution.getStatus());
    }

    @Override
    public void afterJob(JobExecution jobExecution) {

        System.out.println("Job Ended at: "+ jobExecution.getEndTime());
        System.out.println("Status of the Job: "+jobExecution.getStatus());
    }
}
```

What should I do that job should run again after 5 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

Adding a `@Scheduled` annotation on a method does nothing on its own. You need to enable the task scheduling feature that will introspect methods annotated with that annotation and create scheduled tasks for them.

This is done by adding `@EnableScheduling` on one of your configuration classes, please refer to the [task scheduling guide](https://spring.io/guides/gs/scheduling-tasks/) for more details and a complete example.

Comment: I am using this https://howtodoinjava.com/spring-batch/job-scheduler-example/ now just wann know how can i put this `@Scheduled(cron = "0 */1 * * * ?")` instead of application class, to Launcher.